# Access argument from command line

Tags: cicd, salt-stack

I would like to be able to download a file and specify the file path that file is downloaded to using a salt formula. This formula would be triggered through an API call as a final step in a CI/CD pipeline.

How can I pass a command line argument to a salt formula and assign that argument to a jinja variable? A sample psuedo-code of what I am looking for is below:

```yaml
{% set path = salt['arg']('path', '/usr/local/bin') %}

echo_path:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'echo {{ path }}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
salt '*' state.apply pillar='{"path": "/opt/actual/path"}'
```

```
{% set path = pillar.get('path', '/usr/local/bin') %}

echo_path:
  cmd.run:
    - name: 'echo {{ path }}'
```

Pillar can be passed via API calls in a similar way.